# Call another gsp after certain amount of time

Tags: grails

so I want to call a certain gsp after certain amount of time

```
   def index()
   {
           //code here
           //after 30secs
           redirect (action :"anothergsp")
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a [refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) like so:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;url=/somewhere/else" />
    ....
```